# how to customize boot animation in ubuntu 13.04?

Tags: boot

I want to change my boot animation into a video instead of ubuntu with 5 dot. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

It's *Plymouth* you're talking about. You can find the configuration and related files in: `/lib/plymouth/`, `/lib/plymouth/themes/`. To find more about it and for some tips/tricks visit the Ubuntu's wiki on [plymouth](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Plymouth).

Snapshots showing some plymouth themes under *universe* section in *Synaptic Package Manager*:

[image: snap1]
*(search for plymouth in synaptic package manager; if universe repository is not available goto Settings -> Repositories -> Ubuntu Software, and mark the Universe repo., then reload. After that resume your search.)*

[image: snap2]
*(a snapshot of plymouth-theme-solar, a package which contains the solar theme featuring a violent blue flaring star, and other space-like animations.)*

**Links you'd want to visit:**

- [Ubuntu Gnome Paw plymouth theme 0.1](http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/?content=158162)
- [Install And Change Plymouth Themes In Ubuntu Using Zorin Splash Screen Manager](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/10/install-and-change-plymouth-themes-in.html)